# pass JWT token from login to protected routes

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I want to pass a token present in the `token_required` decorator to headers of different protected routes.

This is the code used ( the login endpoint, the protected endpoint, and the requires_token decorator)

```py
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    auth = request.authorization

    if auth and auth.password == "password":
        token = jwt.encode(
            {
                "user": auth.username,
                "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30),
            },
            app.config["SECRET_KEY"],
        )
        return jsonify({"token": token})

    return make_response(
        "Could'nt verify!", 401, {"WWW-Authenticate": 'Basic realm="Login Required"'}
    )
```

```py
@app.route("/protected")
@token_required
def protected():
    return "Only certain people can access"
```

```py
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get("token")

        if not token:
            return jsonify({"message": "Token is missing"}), 403
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(
                token, app.config["SECRET_KEY"], options={"verify_signature": False}
            )
        except:
            return jsonify({"message": "Token is invalid"}), 403

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass something to the **decorated function**, you can add it in the *Keyword arguments* dictionary (`kwargs`) inside the decorator before calling the wrapped function.

for example to pass the `data` value to the protected view, you can use a code like the following

```py
@app.route("/protected")
@token_required
def protected(data=None):
    
    # do something with the data

    return "Only certain people can access"
```

```py
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get("token")

        if not token:
            return jsonify({"message": "Token is missing"}), 403
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(
                token, app.config["SECRET_KEY"], options={"verify_signature": False}
            )
        except:
            return jsonify({"message": "Token is invalid"}), 403
        
        kwargs['data'] = data # add the data to the keyword arguments
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

Anyway, I would advise using a plugin for that like [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)